# Differences between Principled bsdf and other shaders

Tags: shaders

The [Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html) states:

> The emphasis on compatibility with other software means that it
> interprets certain input parameters differently from older Blender
> nodes.

With that in mind there are only two differences the docs state are that the roughness is the same as the square rooted value of the glossy roughness.
Does that mean that I also have to take the square root when converting the roughness values from the e.g. refraction bsdf or anisotropic bsdf?

The other difference the docs state is that the anisotropic reflection is by default rotated by 90 degrees.

I have only found those two differences are those the only differences between the principled bsdf and other bsdfs?

Comment: Hi :). Also Subsurface Scattering is done differently, Fresnel is fully implemented, also Emission has fresnel, and a big difference: Principled BSDF calculates correct lightbounces even from backface normals (important in grass and leafs)

Comment: Ok, could you please further elaborate how exactly the principled bsdf does things differently?

Comment: For example how could emission posisibly have fresnel? Fresnel is an phenomenom exclusive to specular reflection, to my knowledge saying that emission has fresnel does not make any physical sense. And as for the backface light bounces, most shaders (except for the transparancy related bsdfs like glass, etc.) treat foreward and backfacing faces exactly the same, how could the Principled bsdf calculate something more correct than other shaders which already do it fully correctly?

Comment: Hi :). 1) Principled BSDF Emission *does* actually have a *faint* "fresnel-like" effect - compared to regular Emission Shader. 2) I misremembered - Principled BSDF computes *fresnel* [correctly even for backfaces.](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/diffuse-translucency-way-too-difficult-to-set-up-in-cycles/807)

Comment: I can't really elaborate any further, just sharing my experience ;)